# Решение задачи тема Работа со строками

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно-ли из файла записать в переменную String а не как у меня по символьно в char

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте скриншоты, давайте текст. Не считая того, что скриншот не передашь компилятору - так ведь и в поиске ваши вопросы не участвуют... Что до вашего вопроса - то можно читать файл построчно с помощью [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Учту все на будущее спасибо за поправки.

Comment: после того как я записал в getline() как мне пробежаться по символам и вставить перед гласными восклицательный знак?

Comment: Цикл не подойдет?

Comment: Всем спасибо разобрался сам!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void open_and_change(ifstream &in, ofstream &out, string str);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    string str;
    ifstream in("taskstring.txt");
    ofstream out("stringFinish.txt");
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла\n";
    }
    open_and_change(in, out, str);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void open_and_change(ifstream & in, ofstream & out, string str)
{
    string s2 = "uaeio";
    string s1 = "!";
    while (in.peek() != EOF)
{
    getline(in, str);
    string::size_type k = 0;
    k = str.find_first_of(s2);
    while (k != string::npos)
    {
        str.insert(k, s1);
        k = k + 2;
        k = str.find_first_of(s2, k);
    }
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

}